# Managing Drag and drop in Unity 2D

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine

I am novice to Unity and trying to implement a sample game in Unity 2D which constitutes of a several animal sprite and a boat. I have to drag and drop the animals on the boat. only fix number of animals which place at fix place.

I have created animal sprites and boat sprites and using Raycast2D, i am able to detect the animal game-object through collider present in it and also able to drag it by changing its position continuously.

Now I have to create few drop points on boat and drop the animals on it. I am not able to do that . can you guys suggest some ideas. how to do that?

I am not using any UI component and hence inbuilt drag and drop functionality is not working. Is there any way to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to handle dragging object with your mouse, you can create empty game objects(drag points) on the boat as you said, and you can check on the update if the game object has in the radius of the drag point, you can snap the object immediately by setting its transform.position to drag point position. Like,

```
if(isInRadius)
{
   gameobject.transform.position = dragpoint.transform.position;
}
```

You can check bool with the help of collider or manually comparing their coordinates.

If you want to learn how to drag objects, I am pretty sure when you google it, you can find a tutorial about it.